# Shooting from the highway bridge in Tehran Highway: hack or bug?

Tags: battlefield-3

In Battlefield 3's Tehran Highway map, I often notice (for the most part) opponents shooting from the highway bridge itself, almost undisturbed.

Honestly I'm on BF3 since a certain time actually, but I can't figure out how to climb up there.

Is it a hack or is it a bug?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**It's an exploit.**

It is possible to reach the overpass by riding the MAV (a remote-controled, flying gadget for the recon kit intended to be used for reconnnaisance).  Currently, a player can deploy the MAV, stand on top of it, fly it straight upward to an area above the overpass, then jump off.

The ability to ride the MAV is being removed in the upcoming patch.  Patch notes can be found [here](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/news/view/2832654779195992365/).

> -The MAV can no longer be used as an elevator.

Comment: Thanks for that clearification with the patch. Haven't read this in the patchnotes! :)

Comment: Certainly a welcome change.

Comment: A welcome change for sure.

Comment: Well, there is still the option to place the spawn becon below a crane or something, so that you will spawn in mid-air with a parachute and land on the obstacle :(

Comment: You only parachute in to a spawn beacon in certain cases - I don't believe you can in Tehran highway

Comment: Generally speaking, you will parachute to a spawn beacon when it is unobstructed overhead.

Comment: @Albort except for on certain maps(usually those without air vehicles). You will never parachute in on Tehran Highway. Also, with the patch, they made it more difficult, but not impossible. Now you must use teamwork to get on top of it. It has to be someone else's MAV. I don't expect they'll fix this behavior either as they always reward teamwork it seems